# Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I use the Kotlin language to develop Quarkus based application.
Regarding to the https://quarkus.io/guides/kotlin it is possible to write constructor injection in the class definition.

I am trying to do so and receive a warning:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The project is hosted on https://github.com/softshipper/playwithmtls.

Comment: Is this a pure editor issue, or does the code actually not compile?

Comment: No, the code does not compile. The compiler complains `Unsatisfied dependency for type io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity and qualifiers [@Default]`

Comment: IIRC, the `SecurityIdentity` is a `@RequestScoped` bean. Does kotlin allow for field injection? If so: could you try field injection for this field?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try making the resource class `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: I am pretty new in Quarkus. Could you please commit it on github?

Comment: I am not fluent in kotlin, sorry

Comment: What does `@RequestScoped` mean?

Comment: The exact semantics is a bit wordy. It boils down to: "an object of that class is constructed for each request". For details, see the [`@RequestScoped` documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/enterprise/context/requestscoped).

Comment: It doesn't look like you are including any security extensions

Answer (score 0):

Either you're not using the @Inject property or you have to late initialize the SecurityIdentity.

```
@Path("/hello")
class ExampleResource {

   @Inject   
   private lateinit var identity: SecurityIdentity
}
```